# Does a dereferenced Java object still get garbage-collected if it started a thread which is still running?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

Consider the following scenario:

- An object `myObj` is instantiated *locally* in some function `myFunc`.
- `myObj` starts a thread `someThread` which runs some background task, e.g. reads from a socket.
- `myFunc` then returns, causing `myObj` to be dereferenced.

Under normal circumstances, the JVM would just garbage-collect `myObj`. However, if `someThread` is still running, would this still be the case?

I understand that `someThread` itself would ***not*** be GC'd as long as it is still running, but in my code it also needs to access values stored in `myObj`, so it is important that I make sure `myObj` persists while it is still running.

Comment: The Java Virtual Machine specification does not guarantee _anything_ is garbage-collected. What particular JVM are you using?

Comment: @veer I'm intending to run the finished code on an Oracle JVM on Linux. I guess it would be more appropriate to ask whether `myObj` is still _liable_ to being garbage-collected while the thread is running. In this case I need to ensure that something does _not_ get GC'd rather than the other way round.

Comment: @Positronized If your thread somehow has access to an object, it must have a reference to it. And if you have a reference to an object, it cannot be garbage collected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object is only eligible for garbage collection if it has no references to it. You say that `someThread` needs to access values stored in `myObj`, which means it *must* have a reference to `myObj`. This means that `myObj` is not eligible for garbage collection unless `someThread` is also eligible.

You can guarantee that an object will never be garbage collected from underneath you so this, for example, is perfectly safe:

```
void foo() {
    final Object something = new String("I'm alive!");
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {Thread.sleep(10000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println(something);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

`something` is referenced by the anonymous thread so it is not eligible for garbage collection until the anonymous thread is done.

More specifically for your example, this is also safe:

```
void foo() {
    new ThreadStartingObject("I'm alive!");
}

class ThreadStartingObject {
    private String message;

    public void ThreadStartingObject(String msg) {
        this.message = msg;
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {Thread.sleep(10000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

The anonymous inner class representing the thread has an implicit reference to the outer `this`, i.e. the instance of `ThreadStartingObject`. That reference prevents garbage collection.

Comment: If I started the thread in `myObj`'s constructor using `(new Thread(new Runnable() { ... })).start()`, such that the only reference to `myObj` is via `this`, does it still count?

Comment: Yup. Any reference will prevent garbage collection.